# php curl header set currently

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, salesforce

I'm trying to make a post request to salesforce "api". 
however it accepts only content type which is explicitly set to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

When I do this:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_POST => 3,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array (
                        'first_name' => 'foo',
                        'last_name' => 'faa',
                        'email' => 'my.email@gmail.com',
                        'oid' => '#hash',
                        'recordType' => '#hash'
                )),
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
                        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                )
        ));

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

The response headers content-type is always: 
`"text/html;charset=UTF-8"`

The same parameters I send using postman (with the correct header) actually works.

Comment: So the problem is that you're not getting any response from the salesforce api using the code above? Are you getting an error response? Can you provide a link to the salesforce docs that you're using?

Comment: nope. It is a horrible API that doesn't provide any feedback. I know if my request succeeded by going to salesforce -> leads, and check if the lead actually created. I'm pretty sure the problem is that Content-type header. With postman I can post successfully to salesforce. When I change the content-type on postman it also fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `CURLOPT_POST` is `true`, curl sets `Content-Type` of the request to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` automatically; you don't need to do that manually.
You can verify that (as well as check all other "outgoing" headers) by setting `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` to `true` prior to your request, then checking the array returned by `curl_getinfo()`.

I suspect your problem has nothing to do with the request headers but with how curl handles https. Setting these in your `curl_setopt_array()` should help:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
```

Comment: This is my request after the change:
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8',
 CURLOPT_POST=> true,
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=> true,
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($fields),
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
));

Where $fields is an array.
But still the output from curl_getinfo clearly shows: 

content_type: "text/html;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: You are right about the headers though:

the request header string is indeed - request_header: "POST /servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8 HTTP/1.1
↵Host: www.salesforce.com
↵Accept: */*
↵Content-Length: 235
↵Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I'll mark this as a correct answer. It answers the headers problem even though I'm left confused :)